Which beings are unique in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?
The Marvel Cinematic Universe has famously introduced us to the concept of multiple/alternate universes.
We were first introduced solidly to the multiverse within the MCU in Loki Season 1 1. And has introduced us to the concept of the Sacred Timeline - Earth-199999.

There is also a meta-concept of Marvel's multiple cinematic multiverses with the whole Fox/Marvel/Netflix cinematic universes (each receiving their own "Earth-xxxxx" delineations).

The most notable recent ones are:

Earth-10005 - The X-Men Cinematic Universe, the universe where all of Fox's X-Men films take place, including the spin-offs like Logan and Deadpool.
Earth-96283 - The Spider-Man Cinematic Universe, where the three Spider-Man films starring Tobey McGuire take place.
Earth-120703 - The Amazing Spider-Man Cinematic Universe, where the two Spider-Man films starring Andrew Garfield take place.


Consequently, we see that basically every character has many versions or variations of themselves, living within the multi-verse - aptly referred to as "Variants" - leading to a fun way of exploring these variations on-screen, and a tough job for the TVA to keep track of!
We are then given further insight into the Multiverse within the MCU by Oatu "The Watcher" in Marvel's What If... series on Disney+.
I'm intrigued by this idea though. There seems to be only 1 Oatu "The Watcher". He watches the entire multi-verse and as far as we know, has no variants.
My question is: Which Marvel Cinematic Universe beings are unique across the multi-verse?
I've heard that there's potentially only 1 Phoenix Force, and I suspect there might be potentially other beings who have no variants, such as:

Dormammu
Galactus
Ego
Celestials
Alioth (likely, as it lives within the Void and was created during the multiversal war.)


Related question (but not dupe)2:

Which Marvel cosmic entities are unique in the multiverse?




The first inclination being the way Doctor Strange can see multiple possible futures, but Loki was the first to delve into the multi-verse proper
I'm specifically interested in the MCU's multi-verse and not the Marvel (Earth-616) multi-verse



"I'm specifically interested in the MCU's multi-verse and not the Marvel (Earth-616) multi-verse" What makes you think they're separate entities? The MCU's Sacred Timeline has been acknowledged and given the designation Earth-199999 in the Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe, suggesting that it exists in the same multiverse as the comicbook Earth-616.

@LogicDictates And yet the MCU has diverged from the Earth-616 timeline/events.

Kinda interesting to hear that Oatu is unique in the MCU, when you know there are one Oatu per Earth in the comics.

@Möoz - It's entirely normal for different universes in the same multiverse to have divergent histories.

There is only one Phoenix across all multiverses, but please don't think too hard about what implications this has for a time-travelling Rachel Summers. Marvel themselves obviously didn't.

@Möoz That’s kind of the point of different universes though. In fact, that kind of divergence is the whole reason that both Marvel and DC have multiverses, not single universes, it allowed the divergent stories written early on to coexist, and it allows the writers to experiment with interesting new concepts (such as Marvel’s Spiderman Noir, or DC’s Injustice series).

America Chavez
Currently, the only character confirmed in-universe to be unique across the multiverse is America Chavez, who made her debut in Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness (2022).
Multiverse of Madness established a fascinating concept: dreams are actually glimpses into the lives of one's multiversal variants. However, America Chavez, who possesses the extraordinary ability to open portals between universes, never dreams. Despite her extensive travels across multiple universes, she has never encountered another version of herself.
This uniqueness is further emphasized by Wanda Maximoff's relentless pursuit of America throughout several universes. Wanda's singular focus on acquiring America's powers underscores the fact that there is only one America Chavez in the entire multiverse to target.

The really scary thing for America: she is theoretically targeted by an infinite number of Wandas (and similar persons).

At a minimum, the MCU America would seem to be something that's seen rarely. There could be other explanations of the dreaming thing. And, as an old axiom goes - Absence of evidence is not the same as evidence of absence. Perhaps her having proper control of her powers is rare, and she bounces the local "her" out when she comes into a different reality. Mind you, in practice I certainly think this is a valid answer, as any answer is limited by the subset of infinity realities we've seen.

And, on a far more trivial note - this leads one to believe that somewhere, there is at least one reality where people manage to regularly leave home and go about their days for a relatively long time before they realize they're either in their underwear, or naked. Clearly something best explored in a future Deadpool installment.
